# issue with HikariDataSource not showing up in my Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, hikaricp

So I'm working on a project and I'm getting an issue with importing  **import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;**

how do I install it into my IntelliJ?[image]
   The only thing I have is import

> import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.metadata.HikariDataSourcePoolMetadata;

```
package com.example.demoSpring.datasource;
    import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
    **import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;**
    import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.metadata.HikariDataSourcePoolMetadata;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Datasource {
    public HikariDataSource hikariDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .type(hikariDataSource.class)
                .username();
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the contents of your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 3):

Please add this to your **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably concerns your maven dependencies
but this could probably work.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

add this in the dependencies section of your pom.xml,
if that doesn't work or if you already have that dependency listed, try  refreshing your project via maven and stop managing your modules via intellij modules, deleting the folder modules in .idea and deleting modules.xml usually helps,